# how to get values of custom fields to show on drupal template?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a file in my Drupal theme: views-view-fields--homepage-blocks.tpl.php

This is intended to output blocks in the home page. At the moment I am using the following code for testing purposes.

```
<h3><?php echo $fields['title']->content; ?></h3>
<?php
echo $fields['field_url']->content;
echo $fields['field_link_title']->content;
echo $fields['field_homepage_block_image']->content;
echo $fields['body']->content;
```

The title, body and field_homepage_block_image fields are displaying correctly but the field_url and field_link_title fields are not showing at all. These are custom fields that I have just set up - they are of the "text" type. I have cleared the cache and this doesn't seem to make any difference.

The site is online here http://access.kdcloud.co.uk/~dodsgpne/

The blocks I am trying to make work are the 4 grey ones in the middle of the page.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Try to debug `$fields` fields variable and see the output you are getting.

Comment: I've tried with print_r but obviously, this being drupal, that just gives a white screen. I've tried with dpm, using dprint_r but this also gives an error.

Comment: what's the error you are getting ?

Comment: You could try printing it out to watchdog with the following code watchdog('my fields', '<pre>'. print_r($fields, TRUE). '</pre>'); you will find it under admin/reports/dblog

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried using the dsm() function? This may help!